# .Net5 HttpClient concurrency - performance

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, asp.net5

Created a HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory and send 1000 GET call in parallel to WebApi and observed the delay of about 3-5mins for each request.. once this is completed after this again send 1000 GET requests in parallel, this time there was no delay.

Now I increased the parallel request to 2000, for the first batch, each request delay was about 9-11min. And for the second 2000 parallel requests, for each request delay was ~5min(which in case of 1000 requests there was no delay.)

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);



            List<Task> _task = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4000; i++)
            {
                _task.Add(ExecuteRequest(client, i));
                if (i % 2000 == 0)
                {
                    await Task.WhenAll(_task);
                    _task.Clear();
                }
            }

private async Task ExecuteRequest(HttpClient client, int requestId)
    {

        var result = await client.GetAsync($"Performance/{requestId}");

        var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);

    }
```

Trying to understand,

- how many parallel request does HttpClient supports without delay.
- How to improve performance of HttpClient for 2000 or more parallel requests..

Comment: have you considered that maybe the API might be a bottleneck?

Comment: Knowing nothing about you as a developer, I have to wonder exactly how you're queuing thousands of operations to run in parallel. There are many naive ways to do this that will incur a large performance penalty. As a first step, I'd say replace your HTTP calls with no-ops and see how long it takes to run.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann API again a sample ASP.Netcore Web API which  responds to requests with sample response without any time consuming activity like I/O.

Comment: The delay sound like a memory issue.  The initial slow response is the system is trying to get the needed memory to save the results.  Once the app has obtained the needed memory the operating is fast.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede updated the post with sample code

Comment: Another possible bottleneck is your client PC -- initiating and running thousands of concurent network requests  might be quite a job. Try sending requests to smth like google.com, I think you will see the same delays.

Answer (score 1):

> how many parallel request does HttpClient supports without delay.

On modern .NET Core platforms, you're limited only by available memory. There's no built-in throttling that's on by default.

> How to improve performance of HttpClient for 2000 or more parallel requests.

It sounds like you're being throttled by your server. If you want to test a more scalable server, try running this in your server's startup:

```
var desiredThreads = 2000;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out _, out var maxIoThreads);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(desiredThreads, maxIoThreads);
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out _, out var minIoThreads);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(desiredThreads, minIoThreads);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is causing worst-case perf for a "cold" (just newed up or empty connection pool) `HttpClient`.

When you make a new request, it looks for an open connection in the connection pool. When it doesn't find one, it tries to open up a new connection. By throwing a sudden burst at a cold client, most calls to `SendAsync` will end up trying to open a new connection.

This is a problem because a request that needs a new connection will require multiple round-trips to the server, whereas a request on an existing connection will only require a single round-trip. It gets even worse if you use HTTPS. You're heavily dependent on your network latency in this case.

If you are just benchmarking, then you'll want to benchmark steady-state performance, not warmup performance. Benchmark.NET should more or less do this for you.

When you have requests that complete reasonably quick, it can be a lot faster to instead limit your initial concurrency to a smaller percentage of your total requests, and slowly ramp up your connection pool size from there. This allows subsequent requests to re-use connections. What you might try is something like below, which will only allow (rough behavior, not a guarantee) 10 new connections to be opened at once:

```cs
var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
var client = new HttpClient();

async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
   Task t = sem.WaitAsync();
   bool openNew = t.IsCompleted;
   await t;

   try
   {
      return await client.SendAsync(req);
   }
   finally
   {
      sem.Release(openNew ? 2 : 1);
   }
}
```